# Shell script: Delete files when folder with same name does not exist

Tags: shell, grep, sed

I have a set of folders, and a set of `*.DAT` files.
I want to remove a `*.DAT` file if no folder with the same name (without `.DAT`) exists.
It took me some time to come to this solution:

```
find . -type d > dirs.txt
for F in `find *.DAT`
do
  F=$(sed 's|\.DAT||g' <<< $F)
  if grep "$F" dirs.txt; then
    echo "$F found"
  else
    rm $F.DAT
  fi
done
```

But I feel there should be a much easier solution (elegant one-liner? without creating a file? ...?). Am I right?

Comment: Are the folders usually right next to the .DAT file, or are they scattered around?

Comment: @grawity: Folders and .DAT files are in the same folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `sed` to remove the `.DAT` if you are using `bash`: the inbuilt parameter expansion `${F%.DAT}` achieves the same without using a subshell and external program.

If the directories were in arbitrary locations relative to the `.DAT` files, then a directory list file is the most efficient way to solve it, but given that both are in the same location a much more straight-forward answer is:

```
find *.DAT | while read -r f; do if [ -d "${f%.DAT}" ]; then echo "${f%.DAT}" found; else rm "$f"; fi; done
```

Note that this will handle file names with embedded spaces, which your solution doesn't.

For other shells, a similar technique can be used, but I cannot speak for them.